# ASP.NET MVC Route Doesn't Work With .html Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I develop a web application with ASP.NET MVC. I have problem with route.

I need a route like this.
http://localhost/content-name/23.html

I've defined a route for this as follows

```
//i need this route but it's not work
routes.MapRoute(
"GetContent",
"{sefLink}/{contentId}.html",
new { controller = "Content", action = "GetContent" },
new[] { "CanEcomm.Controllers" });
```

But the route doesn't work. IIS is showing me 404 page. When i remove .html extension so the route works.

```
//this route is working. i just remove ".html" extension
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetContent",
    "{sefLink}/{contentId}",
    new { controller = "Content", action = "GetContent" },
    new[] { "CanEcomm.Controllers" });
```

How can i solve this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added HtmlFileHandler to my web.config. And .html routes work now.

```
<handlers>
  <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```